# glTexImage2D to Display Intensity Image

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, access-violation

I'm working to display an image in OpenGL using glTexImage2D, but am having some trouble with the data types...

The image I'm grabbing is a slice of a larger 3D volume and the VolSize_pix struct just gives the dimensions of the volume for indexing:

```
unsigned _int8 *OrthoPlane;
OrthoPlane = new unsigned _int8[VolSize_pix.depth * VolSize_pix.length];
int OrthoPlaneIdx = 0;
int Halfway = (int)floor(VolSize_pix.width / 2);

///printf("Halfway: %d, VolSize_pix.length: %d\n", Halfway, VolSize_pix.length);

for (int VX = 0; VX < VolSize_pix.depth; VX++)
{
    for (int VY = 0; VY < VolSize_pix.length; VY++)
        {
            OrthoPlane[OrthoPlaneIdx] = (unsigned _int8)floor(Volume[VX][VY][Halfway]);
            OrthoPlaneIdx++;
        }
}
```

So, as you can see, it's just an intensity image, not RGB. I'm trying to pass this into a texture OpenGL to display the 2D image as follows:

```
// Load texture
GLuint tex2;
glGenTextures(1, &tex2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
// tell opengl to use the generated texture name
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLsizei width2 = VolSize_pix.length; GLsizei height2 = VolSize_pix.depth;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width2, height2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)OrthoPlane);
```

And for some reason, the screen always just comes up black.

The only way I've been able to see an image is if I allocate a RGB array for OrthoPlane (using the same intensity value for R/G/B) as a floating point value. When I try to use unsigned _uint8, I get nothing. If I keep it as float and try to do intensity, it also fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: What OpenGL version and profile are you using? `GL_LUMINANCE` is deprecated functionality, and only available in old versions and the compatibility profile.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. I'm using 4.5, so probably beyond the deprecation date of GL_LUMINANCE. Does that imply then that the only way to display an intensity image would be to convert to RGB beforehand?

Comment: No, there are formats with only one component in the core profile. E.g. `GL_R8` for the internal format.